# Partially Renaming Columns in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to rename the first N columns of a DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
Dat = pd.read_csv(inputName, delimiter='\t', header=0)
```

The original table looks like this:

```
$Date        $ciq_ticker    $industry        price    ...
'09/30/2016  'AAPL'         'Technology'     100.00
'09/30/2016  'AMZN'         'Consumer'       1000.00
...
```

I want to make some column names more intuitive.  What's in my mind is something like this:

```
descriptors = ['date','ticker','industry']
Dat.columns[:len(descriptors)] = descriptors
```

This gives an error of "Index does not support mutable operations".

I know something like this works:

```
Dat.rename(columns={'$Date': 'date', '$ciq_ticker': 'ticker', '$industry': 'industry'}, inplace=True)
```

But I just don't like the idea of having to type the original column names explicitly.  Truth is, the real table has more than 20 columns that I need to modify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [91]: cols = ['date','ticker','industry']

In [92]: df
Out[92]:
        $Date $ciq_ticker   $industry   price
0  09/30/2016        AAPL  Technology   100.0
1  09/30/2016        AMZN    Consumer  1000.0

In [93]: df.columns = cols + df.columns.tolist()[len(cols):]

In [94]: df
Out[94]:
         date ticker    industry   price
0  09/30/2016   AAPL  Technology   100.0
1  09/30/2016   AMZN    Consumer  1000.0
```

Comment: ok obviously the trick is this .tolist thing.  I cannot directly manipulate column names using Dat.columns[:len(descriptors)].